# whoami returns user but usermod complains it doesn't exist

Tags: ubuntu

I have a linux(ubuntu) user "myuser"

whoami is able to return the username

```
myuser@host:/home/myuser$ whoami
myuser
```

id returns info related to the user too

```
myuser@host:~$ id
uid=43350(myuser) gid=600(staff) groups=600(staff),27(sudo)
```

Now I am trying to run docker commands without sudo. So I tried adding the user to the group, but usermod says user does not exist

```
myuser@host:/home/myuser$ sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
usermod: user 'myuser' does not exist
```

How do I fix this?

Edit: This is on a VM provided by corporate IT in my organization

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/ are better forums for this question.  StackOverflow is for programming questions while AskUbuntu and UNIX & Linux StackExchange cover general questions.

Comment: Fair enough. I have posted the question there too. If it's answered there, I'll take this off from here. Thanks